# Scrapy - Error Importing JSON

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am fairly new to Python and Scrapy but have been able to some basic web scraping. However, I am having issues import JSON data. I have posted the traceback after the code.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
import json

class myspider(Spider):
    name = "jsontest"
    allowed_domains = ["data.sportsillustrated.cnn.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://data.sportsillustrated.cnn.com/jsonp/basketball/nba/gameflash/2012/11/20/32128_playbyplay.json']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        print jsonresponse
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
            self.runUntilCurrent()
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
            call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 382, in callback
            self._startRunCallbacks(result)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
            self._runCallbacks()
        ---  ---
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "jsontest\spiders\jsontest.py", line 10, in parse
            jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
          File "C:\Python27\lib\json__init__.py", line 338, in loads
            return _default_decoder.decode(s)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
            obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
          File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
            raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
        exceptions.ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Can you show us full tracback?

Comment: Running `curl --head http://data.sportsillustrated.cnn.com` returns a 403. Clicking on the link in the browser returns a blank page, so I don't think it's a user agent issue. You may need to adjust your parameters.

Comment: I have added the traceback. If you go to the url, you will notice that that JSON is wrapped in a callbackWrapper. Could that be causing me issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its a jsonp response, see [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) here's one good way to parse it:

```
>>> jsonp = response.body
>>> j = jsonp[ jsonp.index("(") + 1 : jsonp.rindex(")") ]
>>> json.loads(j)
```

also see [this codereview link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2561/converting-jsonp-to-json-is-this-regex-correct)

Comment: Thank you so much. After I posted I realized that it might have something to do with the callbackWrapper. I really appreciate your help.